# Distributed widget - Referencing urls from other host

Tags: webpack

I have a JS plugin that users can embed into their website

Right now using file/url-loader, it generates something like:

`src:url(/fonts/icomoon.eot?slmpmq)`

When I reference URLs, but this looks for the assets on the widget user's website, and not my server where they download it from?

How can I get it to reference my specific domain, even though the script is running on theirs?

Answer (score 0):

The `file` and `url` loaders use your webpack config's `output.publicPath` to create the URL to these resources -- they basically just append the filename to whatever your `publicPath` is. If you set `publicPath` to your site's (or CDN's) URL, the loaders will give you file paths relative to that URL.